# Using the zip:// wrapper for an archive with a single file whose name is unknown

Tags: php, php-stream-wrappers, php-ziparchive

PHP allows to read ZIP files on-the-fly with the `zip://` [wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php):

```php
$fp = fopen ('zip://archive.zip#dir/file.txt', 'rb');
```

All good, when you know the compressed file name. This is not my case: my app has to deal with ZIP archives containing a single file, whose name is unknown before opening the archive.

**Is there an option to tell the wrapper to open the first file in the archive, without the file name?**

*I know I can use [ZipArchive or Zip Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php), I'd just like to keep it simple and use the stream wrapper if possible.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my question after digging through the [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/402eeb85988be91d90a92eff94635b6e9ef6160e/ext/zip/zip_stream.c#L280-L310) of the wrapper.

**There is currently no way to open an archive with the wrapper without providing a file name.**

---

A solution involves using both the wrapper and `ZipArchive`:

```php
$path = '/path/to/archive.zip';

$zip = new \ZipArchive();

if ($zip->open($path) === true) {
    if ($zip->numFiles === 1) {
        $compressedFileName = $zip->statIndex(0)['name'];
        $zipPath = 'zip://' . $path . '#' . $compressedFileName;

        $fp = fopen($zipPath, 'rb');
        // ...
    }
}
```